# Galerkin method to non linear problem

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

We consider the problem 
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u + \omega F(u)= f(x,t), \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0,
\end{equation}
with the initial condition 
\begin{equation}\label{2}
u(x,0)=u_0.
\end{equation}
with $1$ periodic in $x$ boundary conditions.

where $f$ is $1$-periodic function $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}_+$, $f \in C^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}_+)$ and $F$ is non linear function, lipschitzian increasing with $F(0)=0$ and $w>0$.

We search a solution $1$ periodic in $x$: $u \in H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

\bigskip

Our aim is to prouve using the Galerkin methode that the problem  admit a unique solution $u \in H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I try this:

First, we have the following theorem:

\textbf{Theorem}

Let $T > 0$ and $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We suppose that $f \in L^2((0,T),L_{\#}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then there exists a unique solution $u$ such as 
\begin{equation}\label{3}
\displaystyle\int_0^T \langle \partial_t u,v\rangle_{(H^1_{\#})',H^1} \mathrm{d}s 
+\displaystyle\int_0^T (\displaystyle\int_{(0.,1)^n} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \mathrm{d}x) \mathrm{d}s
+ \omega \displaystyle\int_0^T (\displaystyle\int_{(0,1)^n} F(u) v \mathrm{d}x) \mathrm{d}s=
\end{equation}
$$
= \displaystyle\int_0^T (\displaystyle\int_{(0,1)^n} f v \mathrm{d}x) \mathrm{d}s, \ \forall v \in L^2((0,T),H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n)).
$$
\begin{equation}\label{4}
u(x,0)=u_0.
\end{equation}

\textbf{end Theorem}

\textbf{Step $1$}

We introduce an sequence $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ of functions with the following properties:
$$
\begin{cases}
w_i\in H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n),\\
\forall i, w_1,\ldots,w_m \mbox{ are lineary independant },\\
\mbox{finite linear combinations of } w_i \mbox{ are dense in } H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n).
\end{cases}
$$
Such this sequence exists since $H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an separable space.

We search an approximation solution into the form 
\begin{equation}\label{5}
u_m(x,t)= \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{im}(t) w_i(x),
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{im}$ will be determined by the conditions:
\begin{equation}\label{6}
\displaystyle\int_0^T \langle \partial_tu_m,w_j\rangle_{(H^1_{\#})',H^1_{\#}} \mathrm{d}s + a(u_m,w_j)+ \displaystyle\int_0^T (\displaystyle\int_{(0,1)^n)} F(u_m) w_j \mathrm{d}x) ds\\
= \displaystyle\int_0^T(\displaystyle\int_{(0,1)^n} f w_j \mathrm{d}x) \mathrm{d}s, \ \forall 1 \leq j \leq m,
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}\label{7}
a(u,v)= \sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\int_{(0,1)^n} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \mathrm{d} x.
\end{equation}
We complete the system of non linear ordinary differential equations with the initial conditions:
\begin{equation}\label{8}
u_m(0)=u_{0m}, u_{0m}= \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{im} w_i \to u_0 \mbox{ in } H^1_{\#}(\mathbb{R}^n) \mbox{ when } m \to +\infty.
\end{equation}

My question is how we finish this step 1? please.

Comment: Start by proving the boundedness of theese sequences in some spaces, try to get the energy associated to the problem.